Asking for the document of summerzing abnormal fault of magnetic sensors
im delved in a project that requires certain knowledge of magnetic sensors (magnetometers).
The aspect im concerned is the summerization of abnormal/sudden FAULT result of the sensor (just the value, not hardware false), comes along with PROCEDURES lead to corresponding anomaly output.
I did search through many forums, publications,...with key words such as magnetometer fault, heading magnetic sensor anomaly, detect magnetic sensor fault,... However, there was little information gathered to test conducting the unusual results.
Can someone suggest or provide document for this type of problem? I would really appreciate.

It would probably depend on the type and make of the magnetometer. Do you have any documentation from the distributor?

Thanks for your reply. Yes, i have a certain type of magnetometer along with its documentation. Actually, im trying to cover the anomaly response of that sensor as much as possible, since my application needs strict stability. I hope to get some reports of false sensor when people conduct experiment in reality with the steps to reappear the false.

I think we need more details of what you are trying to do, as this covers a large array of devices and situations. Like in a phone? or a laboratory magnetometer? Are you concerned about direction finding, or MRIs, or experiments, or spacecraft, or testing a commercial product? Maybe a gyroscopes with a magnetometer combination is more accurate?
